# use linq to Convert List<List<T>> to List<T> removing duplicate

Tags: linq

I have a class T defined as follow:

```
public Class T
{
  public int myKey{get;set;}
  public datetime other {get;set;}
}
```

How do I convert a `List<List<T>>` to `List<T>`, excluding the duplicates, using Linq?

Without Linq, this could be easily done by this snippet:

```
List<T> r = new List<T>();
foreach (var i in t)
{
   foreach (var j in i)
   {
      if (!r.Select(x=>x.myKey).ToList().contains(j.myKey))
      {
          r.Add(new T(){myKey= j.myKey, other=j.other});
      }
   }    
}
```

The snippet appears to work but is not the most elegant one.

Comment: Your snippet is in fact using Linq in its .Select() and .ToList() calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten your list and `Distinct` to get distinct results.

```
var items = source.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

But it will require you to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods in `T` class. Probably like that:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return myKey.GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as T;
    return other != null && other.myKey == myKey && other.other == other;
}
```

Comment: Why `GetHashCode`? It uses a hashset?

Comment: A kind of. It uses internal class named `Set<TElement>` which is a part of `System.Linq` namespace.